# El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado - JasperReport - Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Trato de cargar un archivo de JasperReport mediante el siguiente código:

```
final InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/View/GestionReportes/InformeMensualLaboratorio.jrxml");
final JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
final JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this);
dialog.setContentPane(jasperViewer.getContentPane());
dialog.setSize(jasperViewer.getSize());
dialog.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/View/icons/logo.png")).getImage());
dialog.setTitle("SIET - Sistema de Información de Enfermedades Tropicales.");
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

No se porque dice que no se encuentra si la ruta del archivo esta bien especificada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Busca el archivo *InformeMensualLaboratorio.class* y verifica que ahí mismo esté el *.jrxml*.

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error: `Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Byte no vßlido 2 de la secuencia UTF-8 de 2 bytes`

Comment: Sugiere que tu jrxml no esta en UTF-8. Asegúrate que tu editor (del jrxml) lo guarde en UTF-8.

Comment: Me fije el código del archivo `jrxml` y esta en UTF-8: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, también fue a la ruta: `Window/Prefrences/General/Workspace` y esta seleccionada la codificación UTF-8

Comment: En la ventana "About/Acerca de Netbeans" ¿Qué dice la línea **System** / **Sistema**?

Comment: Esto: `Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; es_BO (nb)`

Comment: Prueba cambiar la extensión de `.jrxml` a `.xml`, abre el archivo desde Netbeans y observa si te marca errores de sintaxis.

Comment: No marca ningún error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de una ardua investigación al fin pude encontrar la solución, el problema era de que la ubicación donde se encontraba del `JDK` no estaba especificada en mis variables del entorno del sistema y simplemente lo que hice fue agregar la dirección, para mayor detalle pueden entrar a la siguiente pagina que me ayudo a resolver mi problema: https://www.javaer101.com/es/article/3223356.html

Answer (score 1):

Busca el archivo `netbeans.conf` y en la línea que comienza con `netbeans_default_options` añade al final: `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.

Después de reiniciar Netbeans en la ventana de *"Acerca de"* deberá reportar la codificación correcta:

```
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; es_BO (nb)
```

Comment: Se reporta la codificación UTF-8, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Ahora si funciona, lo que hice fue cambiar el `.class` por `.jrxml` del archivo, y se abre correctamente pero el problema es de que no me esta reconociendo los acentos.

Comment: Es recomendable hacer un *"Clean and Build"* al proyecto en Netbeans.

Comment: ¿En dónde no se reconocen los acentos?

Comment: En el JasperReport, por ejemplo, donde debería decir `Otros exámenes` me sale `Otros exÃ?Â?Ã?Â?Ã?Â?Ã?Â¡menes`

Comment: Con respecto al Clean and Build, siempre los hago, tanto el NetBeans como en el JasperReport.

Comment: Cuando te refieres al JasperReport te refieres ¿a la vista de diseño o a la vista previa del iReport/Jaspersoft Studio, ó al jrxml visto desde Netbeans, o a la salida del JasperViewer?

Comment: A la vista del diseño

Comment: Y también en el JasperViewer.